# "adb" can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more informat

Tags: adb

**"adb" can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information**

Comment: Your question is a bit sparse as it just consists of an error message. You should add more details on the used OS, which adb versions (e.g. the one from Android SDK or from a third party site) and so on.

Comment: How did you install `adb`?

Comment: 1) Install the homebrew package manager                                                                                
     /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL 
     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"                         2) Install adb                                                                                                          
    brew install android-platform-tools                                                                              3) Start using adb
     adb devices